# How to run according to interface type

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I need for a code to run according to the interface called, for example in the following code:

```
public class VirtualStreamingFiler : IBFiler, IAFiler
{
    public VirtualStreamingFiler()
    {
        cout << "I like " << interface_func_type_return() << " too!\n";
    }
}
```

interface_func_type_return() will return a string according to the interface used, if IAFiler then return "A_string_request", if IBFiler return "general_purpose_B"

```
int main ()
{
  IAFiler _vpnFiler = new VirtualStreamingFiler();
  return 0;
}
```

so the output here will be:

```
A_string_request
```

How do I do that??

Thank you

Comment: Asssuming that misssing pointer declaration for _vpnFiler is simply an omission, your code is semantically identical to following: `void* tmp = new VirtualStreamingFiler(); IAFiler* _vpnFiler = (IAFiler*)tmp;` Type does not know how it would be used thousands cycles later when it is constructed. Do you consider alternative approaches which will require you to modify interfaces or Filer class, or to create some wrappers around them?

Comment: Thank you for your help! sure, I'm open to try new approach, how do suggest I would do that wrapper? (I'm kinda new to programming so sorry for the low level questions)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function to do two different things, you need two different functions. The only way two different functions in a class can have the same name and same signature is if at least one of them is not virtual and they come from different base classes.

```
class A
{
   public:  void func () { funcA(); }
   private: void funcA() = 0;
};

class B
{
   public:  void func () { funcB(); }
   private: void funcB() = 0;
};

class AB : public A, public B
{
   void funcA() { do something; }
   void funcB() { do something else; }
};
```

This however is a very questionable design and I would think twice before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some code depending on how class would be used after creation, it is better to decouple that code from creation code (and class code in general) and delegate running this code (and figuring out what code should it run) at the moment of object creation to some other entity.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct IAFiler 
{ virtual ~IAFiler() = default; };

struct IBFiler 
{ virtual ~IBFiler() = default; };

struct VirtualStreamingFiler : IAFiler, IBFiler
{};

class VirtualStreamingFilerFactory
{
    template <typename T>
    static std::string usage_type();

public:
    template <typename T>
    static std::unique_ptr<T> create()
    {
        std::cout << "I like " << usage_type<T>() << " too!\n";
        return std::make_unique<VirtualStreamingFiler>();
    }
};

template <>
std::string VirtualStreamingFilerFactory::usage_type<IAFiler>() { return "A_string_request"; }

template <>
std::string VirtualStreamingFilerFactory::usage_type<IBFiler>() { return "general_purpose_B"; }

template <typename T>
std::string VirtualStreamingFilerFactory::usage_type() { return "no_data"; }

int main()
{
    auto _vpnFiler = VirtualStreamingFilerFactory::create<IAFiler>();
}
```